# Flash intermittently disappears in Chrome on Mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome, flash

It seems like every couple of hours flash stops working in Google Chrome on my Mac Book Pro.  Any clues as to why this is happening and how I can prevent it from happening?

version info
8.0.552.224  Stable

Comment: Version number; stable, beta, dev channel? Flash version?

Comment: same thing happening here.  I get "holes" in my browser where flash apps should be.. you can see right through to the window behind.  i've tried completely removing chrome and reinstalling, no difference.